# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Reroute complete domain ( from inside )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

i want to route ALL requests in which the domain name "xyz.com" accours, like:

```
http://xyz.com/asdf/1
http://www.xyz.com/asdf/1
http://www.xyz.com/bcd/asd/2
```

simply to another domain:

```
http://www.abc.com
```

How do i achieve this with the route mechanism of MVC? RouteHandler? MapRoute wildcard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this VIA mvc routing, but you do have a few options:

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(){
    if (Context.Request.Url.Contains("xyz.com"))
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("xyz.com", "www.xyz.com"));
}
```

Comment: I'd have to place the action filter on EVERY action i guess.. so that's not quite of an option for me

Comment: Then just put it in the Global.asax

Comment: As bmancini said, this is without a doubt, a `Global.asax` modification.

Answer (score 0):

A response.redirect will still send a temporary 302 status code.  If you want search engines to understand that your site has moved for SEO purposes you will want to make sure you use a 301.

**Preferred**

If you are using IIS7 you can also accomplish this with the URL Rewrite Module. http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Install it, and stick a rule in the web.config that looks something like this

```
  <rule name="Forward XYZ to ABC" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"  />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xyz\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.xyz\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

**Alternative**

In the global.asax add the following

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(){
    if (Context.Request.Url.Contains("xyz.com"))
    {
       Response.StatusCode = 301;
       Response.RedirectLocation = url;
       Response.End();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with the 2nd one for now UPDATE:

Comment: UPDATE: Ups, seems it's only working on the top-level requests.. The mvc routing jumps in before BeginRequest

Comment: If using .Net 4 you can use `Response.RedirectPermenant(url, true);`.

Comment: I ran this locally using BeginRequest and didn't have any issues.  You may want to revisit your code.